# Cannot connect to the real www.myshopify.com

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, shopify

Just had this error (in Chrome) connecting via https to a shop (API) on myshopify.com from a Windows Server 2003 machine.

Error:

```
The certificate that Chrome received during this connection attempt is not formatted correctly, so Chrome cannot use it to protect your information.
Error type: Malformed certificate
Subject: *.myshopify.com
Issuer: DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA
Public key hashes: sha1/GiBnh3VZhOT1k9C4KDX6w4q9Sec= sha256/6xDMTnv8xhmreRj/tDj7Ii0HVHaA5AFfQZemwKbGOds= sha1/3lKvjNsfmrn+WmfDhvr2iVh/yRs= sha256/k2v657xBsOVe1PQRwOsHsw3bsGT2VzIqz5K+59sNQws= sha1/gzF+YoVCU9bXeDGQ7JGQVumRueM= sha256/WoiWRyIOVNa9ihaBciRSC7XHjliYS9VwUGOIud4PB18=
```

Seems that Shopify have changed their certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Shopify did change their SSL certificate to one that requires SHA-2. Windows Server 2003 doesn't support SHA-2.

There's a hotfix that sorted it: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/938397.